# Can you get into a phd program in engineering with a failed semester

Tags: graduate-admissions

I really want to get my PhD in mechanical engineering. I have a good amount of research done but my GPA is only a 3.0. My first semester of my junior year my husband suddenly deployed right after we closed on our first home, I started a new job, and got a dog. I got a D and an F that semester and my GPA dropped to a 2.0. The following semester I retook the classes and got all A's and a B. I made the deans list and brought my GPA up to a 3.0. Did that one semester kill my chances of getting into a PhD program for mechanical engineering?

Comment: There is a good amount of ppl here with much lower GPA than yours who are faculty members in top 50 schools! So, yes! You can get into a PhD program.

Comment: Look at the similar question and don't hesitate to write a new question if there's something different about your situation.